# Efficient way to add values to panda slices

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I would like to add values to pandas slices in an efficient way, since this function is called very often. The structure looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

mat = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=names, columns=names)

# now comes the `tricky' part
positive_instances = ["a", "e", "c"]
negative_instances = ["d", "b", "f"]

p_mat = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])

mat.loc[positive_instances, positive_instances] += p_mat[0,0]
mat.loc[positive_instances, negative_instances] += p_mat[0,1]
mat.loc[negative_instances, positive_instances] += p_mat[1,0]
mat.loc[negative_instances, negative_instances] += p_mat[1,1]
```

The desired new matrix `mat` looks like this:

```
mat = 
   a  b  c  d  e  f
a  1  2  1  2  1  2
b  3  4  3  4  3  4
c  1  2  1  2  1  2
d  3  4  3  4  3  4
e  1  2  1  2  1  2
f  3  4  3  4  3  4
```

The structure below the comment, is embedded into a for loop. There are several different positive and negative instances.
To add up on the structure of the data:

- `positive_instances` and `negative_instances` are always disjoint and do not need to be of the same length
- The union of `positive_instances` and `negative_instances` is always `names`
- `positive_instances` is always at index `0` of `p_mat` and `negative_instances` is always at index `1`.

I suppose there is a more efficient way to achieve the goal. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: corrected variable names in the code and added desired output.

Edit2: Added information about the nature of `positive_instances` and `negative_instances`

Comment: How are `s_p` and `s_n` defined? Could you show your desired outcome for this particular example?

Comment: @Cleb I corrected the names, and added a desired output.

Comment: Would `positive_instances` always be the every other row/col starting from the first one and same for `negative_instances` starting from the second one?

Comment: @Divakar No. This varies a lot. They do not even have to have the same length.

Comment: Could there be overlap between `positive_instances` and `negative_instances`?

Comment: @Divakar No, `positive_instances` and `negative_instances` are always disjoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could employ NumPy here to assign values into an array efficiently using its broadcasted indexing with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), thus simulating the same behavior with `.loc[row,col]` as done in Pandas. After done with the assignment, we would create the output dataframe.

Thus, the implementation would be something like this -

```
sidx = np.argsort(names)
p_idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(names, positive_instances, sorter= sidx)]
n_idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(names, negative_instances, sorter= sidx)]

n = len(names)
arr = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=p_mat.dtype)
arr[np.ix_(p_idx, p_idx)] = +p_mat[0,0]
arr[np.ix_(p_idx, n_idx)] = +p_mat[0,1]
arr[np.ix_(n_idx, p_idx)] = +p_mat[1,0]
arr[np.ix_(n_idx, n_idx)] = +p_mat[1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=names, columns=names)
```

Runtime test -

Approaches :

```
def func0(p_mat, names, positive_instances, negative_instances):
    mat = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=names, columns=names)

    mat.loc[positive_instances, positive_instances] += p_mat[0,0]
    mat.loc[positive_instances, negative_instances] += p_mat[0,1]
    mat.loc[negative_instances, positive_instances] += p_mat[1,0]
    mat.loc[negative_instances, negative_instances] += p_mat[1,1]
    return mat

def func1(p_mat, names, positive_instances, negative_instances):
    sidx = np.argsort(names)
    p_idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(names, positive_instances, sorter= sidx)]
    n_idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(names, negative_instances, sorter= sidx)]

    n = len(names)
    arr = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=p_mat.dtype)
    arr[np.ix_(p_idx, p_idx)] = +p_mat[0,0]
    arr[np.ix_(p_idx, n_idx)] = +p_mat[0,1]
    arr[np.ix_(n_idx, p_idx)] = +p_mat[1,0]
    arr[np.ix_(n_idx, n_idx)] = +p_mat[1,1]

    df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=names, columns=names)
    return df
```

Timings -

```
In [109]: names = ["a", "f", "d","b", "c",  "e"]
     ...: 
     ...: # now comes the `tricky' part
     ...: positive_instances = ["a", "e", "c"]
     ...: negative_instances = ["d", "b", "f"]
     ...: 
     ...: p_mat = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])
     ...: 

In [110]: %timeit func0(p_mat, names, positive_instances, negative_instances)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.87 ms per loop

In [111]: %timeit func1(p_mat, names, positive_instances, negative_instances)
10000 loops, best of 3: 189 µs per loop

In [112]: 4870.0/189
Out[112]: 25.767195767195766
```

**`25x+`** speedup there!

Comment: Nice work (upvoted)! Any idea why it is so much faster to create a numpy array first and turn it into a pandas dataframe rather than creating the dataframe and modify its elements?

Comment: @Cleb Just an observation point that I have gathered based on answering pandas questions is that manipulating data at array level is more efficient than at native pandas level. This seems to be very true when performing number based computations and for this case with indexing as well.

Comment: Ok, good to know and I'll keep that in mind. Still surprising for me as I thought that pandas uses numpy and c++ under the hood, thus, I would not have expected such huge performance differences.

Comment: @Cleb Well I am not aware of how the pandas is using NumPy, but doesn't look like its that efficient going by these results on assignment/ number crunching problems.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what surprises me but I don't know enough about the underlying architecture.

Comment: Nice work. Unfortunately, I get an index out of bounds for the assignment.         `arr[np.ix_(p_idx, p_idx)] = +p_mat[0, 0]
IndexError: index 41 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 41`

Comment: @swot Is `names` alphabetically sorted?

Comment: @Divakar No. But this should not be a problem. I get them from dictionary keys.

Comment: @swot We were needed to use `sorter` with `searchsorted` for such an unsorted case. Edited.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you. I was not aware of this. I just sorted `names` and now everything works as expected. Thank you for your help.